# Are Macros variables in big query possible?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to big query. In my code I want to be able to declare variable names that I can reference in my table names and where clauses. Is this possible in big query. Just so when I rerun the code I don’t have to find the parts to change.
So I would like to have this at the start of my code that I can change every time I run the code

```
enter code here
Start_date=‘2020-05-01’
End_date=‘2020-06-01’
Selection_Date=‘20200602’
Create table test_selection_date as Select * from sales Where date>= start_date and date<=End_date;
```

Anybody know how this is possible and how I can code it in big query? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should give you good start

```
DECLARE Start_date, End_date, Selection_Date STRING;
SET (Start_date, End_date, Selection_Date) = ('2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '20200602');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(
  "Create table test_%s as Select * from sales Where date>= '%s' and date < = '%s'", 
  Selection_Date, Start_date, End_date
);
```

See more about [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) to tune above to your real use-case

Comment: Thanks I have used your code but when I run the set statement, I get undeclared variable start_date, my code as below:DECLARE Start_date, End_date, Selection_Date STRING;
set (Start_date, End_date, Selection_Date )=('2020-05-01', '2020-05-02', '20200625');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(
  "Create table kk_analytics.KK_test_%s as Select * from sales.customerTransactions Where date>= '%s' and date < = '%s'", 
  Selection_Date , Start_date, End_date
);

Comment: just checked one more time and it perfectly works for me!